# Bootstrap with Picture Slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Code so far:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>

 <head>

    <!-- Naming title and allowing for small-device-viewing -->
    <title>Tech Site</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Calling StyleSheets -->
    <link href = "/ssheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href = "/ssheets/main.css" rel = "stylesheet">

    <!-- Calling JavaScript -->
    <!-- Might be worth moving down to the bottom of 'body' so the page is displayed faster -->
    <script src = "/jscript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "/jscript/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/jscript/main.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Need to display:
         - Navigation Bar
         - Fading Picture
         - 3 Column Testimony Preview
         - Footer
    -->

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <!-- Nav bar set at static to reduce overlapping at top -->
    <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class = "container">

            <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand">Tech Site</a>

            <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class = "dropdown">

                    <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href = "#">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Google+</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Instagram</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <!-- Fading Image -->
    <div class = "container">

        <div class="img-responsive">
            <img style="max-height:450px; width:100%;" src="/images/photo_1.jpg" />
        </div>             

    </div>

    <div class = "container">

        <div class = "row">

            <div class = "col-md-3">

                <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>

            </div>

            <div class = "col-md-3">

                <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>

            </div>

            <div class = "col-md-3">

                <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>

            </div>

            <div class = "col-md-3">

                <h3><a href = "#">$500 Gaming PC Build</a></h3>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-default">Read More</a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

        <div class = "container">
            <p class = "navbar-text pull-left">A Site</p>
            <a href = "#" class = "navbar-btn btn-primary btn pull-right">Find us on Facebook</a>
        </div>

    </div>
        <!-- End of Footer --> 


</body>

</html>
```

CSS is bootstrap 3; as noted in the html code.

At the point of the img responsive tags, I want to have a fading slideshow (slow transition) between three images. However, I have no idea how to do that without messing up the layout. Any ideas?

Comment: why not just use a library for slideshows?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Google comes through yet again - http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-carousel-plugins/

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to word "fade" on the site you just presented.

Comment: Realistically, I just need one photo to fade into another slowly, and then that to fade into another.

Comment: Sorry - you wanted a slideshow - http://wowslider.com/jquery-banner-rotator-catalyst-fade-demo.html

Comment: You could also use http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about the built-in Bootstrap carousel control here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel.

You should easily be able to fit it into your layout.

Comment: I need it to fade, not spin. I've spent some time trying to get the carousel to function appropriately with fading but I cant get it to slowly (calmly) fade into the next photo.